# Is a ring R, modulo an ideal I (generated by x), then modulo an ideal J (generated by n) the same as R modulo the ideal generated by (n,x)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Is the following statement true?

$$ R/(x,n) = \left[ R/(x) \right] / (n) $$

My thinking behind it was as follows:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\left[ R/(x) \right] / (n) & = & \{ r+(n) : r \in R/(x) \} \\
 & = &  \{ \left[ r + (x) \right] + (n) : r \in R \}\\
 & = &  \{  r + ax + bn : r,a,b \in R \} \\
 & = &  \{ r + (n,x) : r \in R \} = R/(n,x)
\end{array}

Comment: An example where this holds is: 
$$ Z[x]/(x,n) = Z/n $$

Comment: You shouldn't reason with set equalities, it's extremely awkward and generally false. Rather, try to define an isomorphism between the two.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the isomorphism theorems:

If $I \subset J$, we have a canonical isomorphism $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$.

Take $I=(x), J=(x,n)$.